# test database application in android on external device?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-emulator

i have made a android application that uses a database. I have run the application on the emulator and it runs fine. Now i want to test the application on an external device.
Earlier when i was not using the database functionality in the application, it was running fine on the external device.
Now that i am running the same thing with a database, a security exception is being thrown.
I am not able to push my database in the android device.
How do i push my sqlite database into my android device?
any help is appreciated.
thank you in advance.

Comment: how are you trying to do so? what's the exception it's throwing?

Answer (score 0):

I recently asked a [database related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935388/ddms-file-explorer-cant-access-data-data-htc-desire-hd) about not being able to pull an SQLite database from an android device.  The given solution ought to be able to work in reverse, too, if you copy your database to the SD card and run a helper function in your application to move it across to the correct location.