# React-native - SQLite - Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, react-native

Well, I'm developing an android application with React Native, and I decided to use SQLite as a database

On the site 'https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage' it explains a bit of how to use SQLite with react-native, the problem is that I work with a Windows operating system computer.

I'm following all the steps of the site, but when I get into 'Setting up your project to import the pre-populated SQLite database from iOS application', I'm confused as I'm developing an Android application, and it teaches only for iOS.

I wonder if it has a way of doing the same thing for Android. Can you help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create/open a database in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10052544/how-do-i-create-open-a-database-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using android then you can jump directly to [Opening a Database](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage#opening-a-database).

As the documentation says, the step you are stuck in is for iOS only.

Comment: Do I need to create the 'www' folder?

Comment: If you want a pre-populated db then yes, otherwise no.